# Custom Vertical ProgressBar in LibGDX

Tags: java, layout, libgdx, progress-bar, skin

I want to create Custom vertical progress bar with non linear background

[image]

In previous implementation I used [skin composer](https://ray3k.wordpress.com/software/skin-composer-for-libgdx/) , but as I know it works perfect with simple regular shapes (the knob part resize on the all background image so it looks bad in my example ). I also try to hack using several layer behind the progress bar, but for this case the background behind progress bar is transparent.

I suppose [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25537/how-do-i-make-a-progress-bar-with-letters-that-get-filled-in) solution can solve my issue but unfortunately I dont understand how can I implemented that solution.

I also try to crop the inside part ([that reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610440/crop-image-using-libgdx)), whenever the progress is changed but I dont think that is the best solution (also the increase/decrase animation cannot be simple enabled )

Answer (score 0):

Could you draw the full red progress bar and then load peices of it until it fills up the whole thing?

Here is a way to get pixels from a png image and you could wirrite your own parser:
[How do I read pixels from a PNG file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444869/how-do-i-read-pixels-from-a-png-file)

Or you could search Google for how to get peices of a png or bitmap.